# Using contains on an ArrayList with integer arrays

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, contains

I have an `ArrayList<int[]>`, and I add an array to it.

```
ArrayList<int[]> j = new ArrayList<int[]>();
int[] w = {1,2};
j.add(w);
```

Suppose I want to know if `j` contains an array that has `{1,2}` in it without using `w`, since I will be calling it from another class.  So, I create a new array with `{1,2}` in it...

```
int[] t = {1,2};
return j.contains(t);
```

...but this would return false even though `w` was added to the list, and `w` contains the exact same array as `t`.

Is there a way to use contains such that I can just check to see if one of the elements of the `ArrayList` has the array value `{1,2}`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Arrays can only be compared with Arrays.equals().

You probably want an ArrayList of ArrayLists.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> j = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
ArrayList<Integer> w = new ArrayList<Integer>();
w.add(1); w.add(2);
j.add(w);
ArrayList<Integer> t = new ArrayList<Integer>();
t.add(1); t.add(2);
return j.contains(t); // should return true.
```

Comment: That won't solve the real problem unfortunately.  What if `w` had `1,2,3`?

Comment: I thought the user wanted to compare exact arrays, he didn't mention a slice of the array.

Answer (score 11):

The problem here is that arrays don't override [`Object.equals(Object)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29), So the comparison between two list entries happens with the default equals() implementation

```
// from Object.class
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
return (this == obj);
}
```

So you have to iterate over the list and check all entries using [`Arrays.equals(int[], int[])`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals%28int%5B%5D%2C%20int%5B%5D%29). Here's a Helper method that does this:

```
public static boolean isInList(
    final List<int[]> list, final int[] candidate){

    for(final int[] item : list){
        if(Arrays.equals(item, candidate)){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

---

**Update:** Ever since Java 8, this has got a lot simpler:

```
public static boolean isInList(
        final List<int[]> list, final int[] candidate) {

    return list.stream().anyMatch(a -> Arrays.equals(a, candidate));
            //  ^-- or you may want to use .parallelStream() here instead
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate through the list and manually check whether an array matches your criteria.

```
public static boolean containsSubArray(List<int[]> j, int[] sub) {
   for ( int[] arr : j ) {
      if (arr contains elements of sub) {
         return true;
      }
   }
   return false;
}
```

If you want an exact match, you can make use of `Arrays.equals()`.  I don't think there's a library function to do a contains all on an array though, so you would have to write that yourself if that's what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

from java api:

```
public boolean contains(Object o)
```

> Returns true if this list contains the
>   specified element. More formally,
>   returns true if and only if this list
>   contains at least one element e such
>   that `(o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e))`.

since `int[]` is a primitive, im pretty sure no .equals method exists so its my guess it would always return false.

I would recommend a different way of storing the data? maybe with a key of some sort?

Comment: `int[]` isn't actually a primitive.  All arrays are an `Object` and inherit its implementation of `equals()` which returns true if the operands are the same *instance* (`==`)

Comment: int[] is not primitive. int is. int[] extends Object, but doesn't override `equals()`

Comment: ah my b. i was trying to get at the fact that it doesn't override the equals() method and thusly cannot be used for contains.

Answer (score 0):

"contains" contract checks for equality. So in your case what is failing is equality of int[]. Since `Array` does not override the equals method from `Object` you will need a workaround to check for containment.

If you need to check for containment within the `Array` then you are left with no choice but to iterate through the ArrayList and do the comparison yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Two java array arrays are equal iff they have the same object reference. Content doesn't matter.

You're looking for a way to check if they have an equal content. This could help:

```
 Arrays.equals(new int[]{1,2}, new int[]{1,2});   // evaluates to true
 Arrays.equals(new int[]{1,2}, new int[]{2,1});   // evaluates to false (!)
```

If order shouldn't affect equality, then you will have to implement a static equals method by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

First they are not the same Object reference, so they are not equal. equals() will return false.
For your condition, you will need to implement a method to compare them yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you have one array and want to compare that all elements of array are present in list:

```
Long[] array1 = {1111L, 1112L};
Long[] array2 = {1111L, 1114L};
List<Long> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(1111L);
list.add(1112L);
list.add(1113L);

Arrays.asList(array1).stream().allMatch(val -> list.contains(val)); //return true
Arrays.asList(array2).stream().allMatch(val -> list.contains(val)); //return false
```