# java - check an array of objects exist in a list

Tags: java, list

I have a list of object array in this structure:

```
List<Object[]> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
numbers.add(new Object[]{1, 2, 3, 4});
```

I want to check whether an array of objects exist in that list. The `contains` method always returns `false`. I use `contains` in this way:

```
if(numbers.contains(new Object[]{1,2,3,4}))
```

This condition always returns false. What's the problem?

Comment: can you have array of Integers instead of objects?

Comment: `new Something()` create a new instance so both your `new Object[]{1, 2, 3, 4}` are differents (not the same hashcode)

Comment: @RC. but  the `contains` method uses `equals` method to find the matching object

Comment: @sidgate - Yes, but for arrays, `equals()` sin't overriden and hence you will only be checking references

Comment: in that case instead of using `List<Object[]>` you should use `List<List<Object>>`

Comment: I'm *fairly* certain that the dupe for this one is right; even though there is the proviso that `new`ing the instances is causing some of the immediate pain, that alone won't be sufficient to do it [per this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4849107/1079354).

Comment: @sidgate, see http://ideone.com/3Kl5uR

Comment: @Makoto Extracting to value to a variable is enough to get true in this case.

Comment: @MarounMaroun:  Yes, but that's incomplete.  There's no guarantee that the OP is always creating the arrays in the same place that they're searching through the arraylist.  In *practice*, I would expect that to *not* be the case.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
List<Object[]> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
numbers .add(new Object[]{1, 2, 3, 4});
boolean b = list.stream().anyMatch(o -> Arrays.deepEquals(o, new Object[]{1, 2, 3, 4}));

System.out.println("b = " + b);
```

And the result is:

```
b = true
```

Comment: I get the feeling that [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4849051/1079354) would benefit *more* from that answer, as a Java 8 option.

Comment: I have checked in my PC, it works well, you can try.

Comment: You should try this, don't use new Operator
List<Object[]> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
  Object[] obj = new Object[]{1, 2, 3, 4};
  numbers.add(obj);
  if(numbers.contains(obj))
   System.out.println("True");
  else 
   System.out.println("False");

Comment: Yes, I know it works.  That's probably why I haven't downvoted it.  The main point here is that the duplicate question which I've linked to in a response (and subsequently voted to close this question as) would benefit far more from this answer, since first - this is a duplicate question and second - a Java 8 option is indeed missing from the linked dupe.