# Java ArrayList of Arrays contains returns unexpected result

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, contains

I am writing code for a game of Tic-Tac-Toe between a computer and a user. To make a move, a list of spots not occupied on the board is provided as a parameter, which for the user is really only useful in comparing if the input is in the list or not. If so, that constitutes a legal move.

Here is my code. It keeps saying that the new move is not contained in the list and I do not know why. I have searched the database here for a similar issue and found a few related but not conclusive ones.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class UserTTTPlayer implements TicTacToePlayer{

@Override
public int[] makeMove(ArrayList<int []> unusedMoves) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Your move, user?");
    String input = in.nextLine();
    int [] move = checkInput(input, unusedMoves);
    while (move == null){
        input = in.nextLine();
        move = checkInput(input, unusedMoves);
    }

    return move;
}

private int [] checkInput(String input, ArrayList<int []> unusedMoves){

    System.out.println("Unused moves: ");
    for (int [] move: unusedMoves)
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(move));

    //error checking for the length of the input
    if (input.length() < 1 || input.length() > 2){
        System.out.println("Invalid input. Please try again.");
        return null;
    }
    else{

        //convert the input from string to int
        int col = input.charAt(0) - 'a';
        int row = input.charAt(1) - '0';
        int [] move = {row, col};
        System.out.println("Intended move: " + Arrays.toString(move));
        System.out.println(unusedMoves.contains(move));

        //error checking for the bounds of the board
        if (col > 3 || col < 0 || row > 3 || col < 0){
            System.out.println("Invalid input.");
            return null;
        }

        //error checking for if the space is available
        else if (!unusedMoves.contains(move)){
            System.out.println("That space is already occupied.");
            return null;
        }
        return move;
    }
}
}
```

This is the output from that. The board and other printing is from a different class, but unrelated to the problem, I think. I print out the list which says that it has the new move in it, yet contains still returns false.

```
You go first. You will be X's.
  a b c
0 - - - 
1 - - - 
2 - - - 

Your move, user?
a0
Unused moves: 
[0, 0]
[0, 1]
[0, 2]
[1, 0]
[1, 1]
[1, 2]
[2, 0]
[2, 1]
[2, 2]
Intended move: [0, 0]
false
That space is already occupied.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Array does not implement equals method, which used in list for contains method

Comment: Your comparing `col` three times: `col > 3 || col < 0 || row > 3 || col < 0`. Just spotted it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4849051/using-contains-on-an-arraylist-with-integer-arrays).  Does that help at all?

Comment: `!unusedMoves.contains(move)` , this code won't work, as you are comparing array objects, which will not give correct result. you need to check array elements, something like `unusedMoves.get(0)[0]==move[0] && unusedMoves.get(0)[1]==move[1]`. And you may need a loop to go over `unusedMoves` list

Comment: @Amit.rk3 a less verbose way would be to call `Arrays.equals(unusedMoves.get(0), move)`.  Would still require the loop like you said

Comment: @Hill , yup that's better :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comments explained, `unusedMoves.contains(move)` doesn't work as you might expect. The `.contains` method uses the `.equals` method of the objects inside the list to check if the given value is equal to one of the elements. However, the `.equals` method of arrays doesn't compare the elements, it compares only identity of the arrays using `==`.

For example:

```
int[] arr = {1, 2};

// prints false, as the array in the list is not *identical*
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(new int[]{1, 2}).contains(arr));

// prints true, as the array in the list *is* identical
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(arr).contains(arr));
```

Consider this helper method:

```
private boolean contains(List<int[]> list, int[] arr) {
    return list.stream().anyMatch(x -> Arrays.equals(x, arr));
}
```

With this helper method, you can replace `unusedMoves.contains(move)` with `contains(unusedMoves, move)`, and it should work as expected.