# ArrayList<String[]> may not contain objects of String

Tags: java, android, string, arraylist, sonarqube

Kindly check the below code, This is showing some warning,

`ArrayList<String[]> may not contain objects of String`

```
ArrayList<String[]> mName = new ArrayList<>();
mValue = "John";
if (!mName.contains(mValue)) {

    String[] details = new String[]{"Driver", "Part-time"};
    mName.add(details);

}
```

Comment: `if (!mName.contains(mValue)) {`  it contains String Arrays, so how can this work?

Comment: a `List` of `String[]` can't have `String`s? the error tells you exactly what is wrong, read it

Comment: Your own title just says it all. You have a list of String array's, so how is that list ever going to contain a String object

Comment: I thought it was  ArrayList<String> on the first look and, Sorry now understand the issue. Thanks for pointing out the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `if` condition returns false because `String[]` and `String` are **different types**, so the `equals` method of String class **will always return false**. You must rethink your code. Please look also at this similar question: [Using contains on an ArrayList with integer arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4849051/using-contains-on-an-arraylist-with-integer-arrays)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the problem

Answer (score 2):

You have created **ArrayList** of **String[]** or String arrays. But you are checking that if  `ArrayList<String[]>` mName contains a string. Java won't allow it. In this case you can check that your `ArrayList` cantains any `String[]` or not. So, if you want to check that string `"John"` is in the `ArrayList` then change

```
ArrayList<String[]> mName = new ArrayList<>();
```

to

```
ArrayList<String> mName = new ArrayList<>();
```

If you want to keep your previous code then change `mValue` to String array. Change

```
mValue = "John"
```

to

```
String[] mValue = new String[]{"John"};
```

**N.B:** `mValue = "John"` this line is missing a `;`