# How to check if an object exists in a LinkedList in java?

Tags: java, linked-list, contains

A LinkedList contains a set of `Integer[]`. Each `Integer[]` in the list has 2 numbers.
Ex of the linked list:

```
Integer[]{1,2}, Integer[]{2,3}.....
```

Before adding another `Integer[]` to this `LinkedList`, I wanto check if another `Integer[]` with the same data already exists.

Ex: Object to add = `Integer[] {2,3}`. But this already exists in the LinkedList.

So I want to avoid adding this.

How to verify that object already exists? Is there an inbuild function that can be used? `contains()` didnt do the trick.

Comment: Is Java 8+ allowed?

Comment: If your list contained a class that holds two integers, and if that class overrides equals and hashCode, reflecting what those integers are, then simply call `contains(...)` on the list. If you went this route, then best to make the class immutable.

Comment: Consider using a `Set` and creating a class for your integer-pairs with correct `equals` and `hashcode` methods.

Comment: That's a good reason to work with a better data type. Why do you use `Integer[]` if it only has two values? Create a proper model class, then `contains()` would work as expected.

Comment: yes java8 is allowed

Comment: if I have to replace Integer[] with another type, what would that be? The reason I used Integer[] is to store coordinates of a graph

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using contains on an ArrayList with integer arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4849051/using-contains-on-an-arraylist-with-integer-arrays)

Comment: Well, actually an `ArrayList` could work, but perhaps it would be better long-term to create a `Point` class of some kind.

Comment: Use a `Set<Point>>` instead: no duplicates as `.equals` okay and `add ` then returns false.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you better use a specific class if you are treating coordinates, as an `Integer[]` is useless for only two numbers, and will cause some problems with `contains()` and other `List` methods like `.sort()` as well.

You better create a `Coordinate` class, which will hold the two values:

```
public class Coordinate{
    private int x;
    private int y;

    //getters and setters, constructor
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o == this) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Coord)) {
            return false;
        }
        Coordinate coord = (Coordinate) o;
        return coord.x == x &&
                coord.y == y;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = 17;
        result = 31 * result + x;
        result = 31 * result + y;
        return result;
    }
}
```

Then you can use:

```
LinkedList<Coordinate>
```

**Note:**

Note that using a `Set` implementation will be better here, it will prevent having duplicates in the set of coordinates, so we don't need to check for it manually.

Comment: Abbreviations are bad practice and discouraged unless they are universally accepted such as `Utils`. `Coordinate` is therefore preferred.

Comment: Caveat: If you're going to use the x and y fields within equals and hashCode, then they should be immutable (as per my comment to the OP's question).

Comment: @chsdk Rather than a class we can use `Stream` with `Set` to make it short.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I just tried to produce a quick class for the example purpose, yes it would be better defined it as immutable. Thank you for the tip anyway :)

Comment: @ShubhenduPramanik Yes it would be another good alternative to use `Stream` and yes for the `Set` point, I was about pointing it out.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can do it the dumb way:

```
boolean exists = false;
for (Integer[] integers : list) {  // list being the LinkedList
    if (Arrays.equals(integers, value)) {
        exists = true;
        break;
    }
}
if (!exists) {
    list.add(value);
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest doing what chsdk posted though.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Stream` with `Set` to solve your problem like below:

```
 List<Set<Integer>> list = new LinkedList<>();
    list.add(Stream.of(1, 2).collect(Collectors.toSet()));

    Set<Integer> s1 = new HashSet<>();
    s1.add(1);
    s1.add(2);

    System.out.println(list.contains(s1));

    Set<Integer> s2 = new HashSet<>();
    s2.add(1);
    s2.add(4);
    System.out.println(list.contains(s2));
```

***O/P:***

true

false

**N.B:** You can use `ArrayList` because yo preserve the sequence as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you really really want to do that with `contains()` (or have no other choice by whatever reason), you can implement it like that:

```
    final Integer[] newPair = {2, 3};
    final boolean exists = values.contains(new Object()
    {
        // note that List.contains() javadoc explicitly specifies that 
        // newPair is used as the receiver not the argument for equals()
        @Override
        public final boolean equals(final Object listElement)
        {
            final Integer[] otherPair = (Integer[]) listElement;
            return Arrays.equals(newPair, otherPair);
        }
    });
```